# How can I protect against Slowloris on a NGINX server?

Tags: nginx, ddos, denial-of-service

Well, I recently discovered that my site(s) were vunerable to the Slowloris attack.

A few seconds in after testing the attack on my server just to verify it was Slowloris that was causing the issue, it instantly started having connection issues. How would I protect against this on an nginx server?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using [ngx_http_limit_conn_module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_conn_module.html)